# application style logging for postgresql

Tags: postgresql, logging

I'm looking for a logging framework for postgresql. Something like oracle's [log4plsql](http://log4plsql.sourceforge.net/docs/UserGuide.html) or java's log4j. I want to log an ETL process developed using PL/pgSQL in different levels.

I've looked into postgres [reporting and logging](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-logging.html) mechanizem but it's seems more like a tracing solution rather then application logging. First, the output is to a file. Second , all process are handled in that mechanize and I want to log only certain operations.

I'm new to postgres and at the moment it seems that there are many restrictions that makes developing a logging framework like that a very difficult task. For example - I understand that there are no autonomous transactions so I need to use a hack with a dblink. No packages so I cant really define global variables for logging level etc ...

Before I run and develop my own custom made solution I wanted to know if there is already a framework out there.

Answer (score 1):

As you say there isn't support for autonomous transactions within PostgreSQL as of 9.3 - nor transaction control within a function.

However pl/pgsql isn't your only option. If I really wanted to do something like this I'd use the untrusted version of pl/perl or pl/java and rely on log4perl or log4j.